# Showing Agent Names side by side in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have 2 columns first one `Id` and another is `Agent`. Each Id has different Agents.
Now I need to show names besides each ID.
But I am getting data like below.
I kept ID and name in rows shelf

Expected out put :

```
ID      Name    Name    
12345   Ram     Rajesh  
4444    Ravi    Raghu   
3333    Reena   Teena James
```

Out put I am getting :

```
ID      Name
12345   Ram
12345   Rajesh
4444    Ravi
4444    Raghu
3333    Reena
3333    Teena
3333    James
```

Comment: can you please add some code. So, error can be found.

Comment: @bestiosdeveloper Its directly from the table

Comment: try ading groupBy on ID field.